# Requesting New Role and Responsibility

Tags: title, job-description

I have been working in the same position for almost 2 years now at the same company. Since commencement of my role, I believe I have developed key understanding of jobs performed by other departments. As such, I would like to request a review of my position to better suit the jobs I am performing.

The main roles for my position are:

1. Answer incoming phone calls for IT related questions;
2. Maintain a ticketing system and collect relevant information to escalate
3. Liaise with other departments to get a customer's issue resolved.

Now I do not want to say that "this role is beneath me", but I would like to ditch the requirement of categorising tickets and answering phone calls, and simply free myself up to do more work. Because of the company we work in, hiring another staff member to do my role is not an option.

I would like to, without being rude or inconsiderate, ask about the feasibility of offloading the requirement of answering most (obviously not all) of the phone calls and ticket assignment to my co-worker whilst I engage in the more technical work.

What would be the best solution to this issue? I'd like to bring it up with my supervisor and ask if it a valid option. Of course, I do not want to place the burden on my co-worker to simply answer phones and tick fields all day long.

Comment: technical work being "liasing with other departments"?

Comment: @Kilisi No, actually performing the tasks such as network diagnostics, software troubleshooting, hardware troubleshooting etc. I sort-of "bridge" a few departments and perform the low-level work for them.

Comment: Well, I have been there. 2 years is definitely long enough to learn that much, have you considered getting a qualification, a basic MCP or A+, assuming you don't already have those. That would make a huge difference if you're tired of phone answering, and it's cheap enough to accomplish with some effort.

Comment: @Kilisi Yes, I will be looking at getting such a qualification soon. I am just ending a Cert IV in Network Administration (That I undertook to help with this situation). Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why isn't hiring another staff member an option? If you're qualified to do the more technical work, then freeing up your time so you can focus on that should be more than worth the cost of a first-level support rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with asking, try and make a list of how it would advantage the company and discuss it with your manager. Quite possibly he/she may feel that you're ready for a full technical role or ready to start training seriously for one.

When it comes to advancing your own job prospects, worrying about colleagues is very nice, but can hold you back.

Comment: I fully agree with you. However in this scenario due to work, I cannot simply migrate positions. I need to retain some ties to the helpdesk role to assist my co-worker.